Variance Swap Valuation
I am trying to find the future volatility of a variance swap. I have a trade which has already commenced and i am valuing it midway. I can observe the past variance till my valuation date but i am not sure how to estimate the future variance till the expiry date. Is there a simple approximation i can do if i have the vol surface ?
I have also read a Derman's approximation but not sure how to find the skew from the vol surface.
